# how can i delete javaDB database folder

Tags: javadb

I am using JavaDB in my application,different database files are created on each operations and i want to delete all database files at the close of application but on close database folder not deleted from file system path using file method like(FileUtils.forceDelete(File)). In data base folder i have one .lck file may be due to this file database folder is not deleted and in application i have closed all open connections related to these database.
so how can i delete JavaDB database folders.
is needed for my application. 
is any body have idea related to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your application folder (if you use NetBeans it will on your NetBeans Project folder), you will find a folder with your database name there. Delete it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running JavaDB as a service? If yes, you have to shut it down before you can delete the db folders.

```
java -jar derbynet.jar shutdown
```